# pyspark - Aggregate using RDDs much faster than DataFrames

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, rdd

I am trying to do a simple lookup and aggregation on (big) CSVs from google grams. For that, I have my `patterns_set` broadcast variable where belongs all the keys I wanna lookup, and then I look for them in `df`, a `pyspark.sql.DataFrame` created with the `databricks.csv`format. 
So I want to group by `ngram` (col 0) then sum on `match_count` (col 1).

But there are magnitude differences between computing that job with RDDs or with DataFrames when I try locally (16ms vs 43s). Not exactly sure that happens also on the cluster though -- **is that expected** ?

```
%%time
from operator import itemgetter, add
df.rdd.filter(lambda x: x[0] in patterns_set.value).keyBy(itemgetter(0))\
.mapValues(itemgetter(1))\
.mapValues(int)\
.reduceByKey(add)
```

And that takes :

```
CPU times: user 7.04 ms, sys: 3.24 ms, total: 10.3 ms
Wall time: 16.7 ms
```

But when trying with dataframes :

```
%%time
df.filter(df.ngram.isin(patterns_set.value))\
  .groupby('ngram').sum('match_count')
```

The wall time is way way bigger

```
CPU times: user 6.78 s, sys: 1.54 s, total: 8.32 s
Wall time: 43.3 s
```

Comment: Is this the actual code you have in notebook cells? Nothing more?

Comment: Besides imports, loading the `df` using `databricks.csv` and loading `patterns_set` using pickle (and broadcasting it), that's all, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't measure what you think it does.

The first snippet is very fast because it does almost nothing. RDD transformations are lazy so data is not touched at all (or is accessed only to infer schema, depending on the upstream code).

With what you've shown it is not possible why the second snippet is slow, but the best bet is either metastore initialization (if this snippet was actually executed first) or time required to compute execution plan (this might happen especially with large number of columns). Same as the first snippet it is (more or less) lazy, so data is actually not processed.